# How to get the IPv6 address of an interface under linux

Tags: python, linux, ipv6

Do you know how I could get one of the IPv6 adress of one of my interface in python2.6. I tried something with the socket module which lead me nowhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I'll surely go with this, it sould be working good, even if I find that really ugly.

```
step1 = Popen(['ip','addr','show','br0'],stdout=PIPE)
step2 = Popen(['grep','inet6'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=step1.stdout)
step3 = Popen(['sed','-e','/fe80/d','-e','s/ *inet6 *//g','-e','s/\/64.*$//g'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=step2.stdout)
step4 = Popen(['tail','-n1'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=step3.stdout)
step4.communicate()[0]
```

Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 5):

The [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/) module should do it.

```
import netifaces
addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
addrs[netifaces.AF_INET6][0]['addr']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sadly I want to stay very simple in this script which should run on a lot of different environment. So I was looking for something which wouldn't necessitate an easy_install.
But still, it works great, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply run 'ifconfig' with a subprocess.* call and parse the output.

Comment: I thought about that, and I have actually a ready (and long) command to get my Ipv6 well formated. But it really look ugly. It must exist a righter way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
with open('/proc/net/if_inet6') as f:
    for line in f:
        ipv6, netlink_id, prefix_length, scope, flags, if_name = line.split()
        print(if_name, ipv6)
```

https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/ch11s04.html

(Or do it the hard way using netlink: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701203 )

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactoring of the OP's answer into a single subprocess. I had to guess some things about the output format of `ip`.

```
output = subprocess.run(
    ['ip','addr','show','br0'],
    text=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
for line in output.stdout.splitlines() 
:
    if "inet6" in line:
        if "fe80" not in line:
            addr = line.split("inet6")[1].strip()
            addr = addr.split("/64")[0]
print(addr)
```

In general, simple search and string substitution operations are both easier and quicker to perform directly in Python. You want to avoid running more than a single subprocess if you can. (Better still if you can do everything natively in Python, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer using [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import psutil
import socket

def get_ipv6_address_from_nic(interface):
    interface_addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs().get(interface) or []
    for snicaddr in interface_addrs:
        if snicaddr.family == socket.AF_INET6:
            return snicaddr.address
```

Example:

```
>>> get_ipv6_address_from_nic("lo")
'::1'
```