# integer to string conversion in same python program

Tags: python, string, integer

Hi  I am trying to use ipaddress which is integer in this program. but I need to call this as string in `response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "-I" + str(mystring))`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
interface = os.system("ifconfig ge1 | grep UP")
ip = os.system("ifconfig ge1.1 | grep UP")
ipaddress = os.system("ifconfig ge1 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 |  awk '{ print $1}'")
print ipaddress
mystring = repr(ipaddress)

print mystring

if interface == 0:
 print interface, ' interface is UP!'
 hostname = "8.8.8.8"
 response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "-I" + str(mystring))
 if response == 0:
  print hostname, 'is up!'
 else:
   print hostname, 'is down!'
else:
   print interface, ' interface is down!'
```

Comment: Import ipaddress class

Comment: os.system() returns exit status code, not an IP address !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python/24196955#24196955

Comment: My idea is to form a command to see destination 8.8.8.8 is reachable form interface whose ip address keep on changing. if destination is reachable, I want to consider the exit code is true and then I will do some other extra work. for eample : ping -c1 8.8.8.8 -I (here I need to have dynamic ip address assigned on Ethernet port 0)

Answer (score 0):

`os.system("ifconfig ge1 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 |  awk '{ print $1}'")` will not return to you IP address instead **EXIT STATUS** code, so you need to use a module that gets you the IP address of your interface(eth0, WLAN0..etc),

As suggested by the @stark link comment, use [netifaces package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/) or [socket module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#module-socket), examples taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python/24196955#24196955) :

```
import netifaces as ni
ni.ifaddresses('eth0')
ip = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[2][0]['addr']
print ip
```

===========================================================================

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

get_ip_address('eth0')
```

EDIT-1:

It is recommended that you run your terminal commands through [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) rather than **os.system** as I've read it's a lot more safer.

Now, if you wan to pass the result of ip_address into your `ping` command, here we go:

```
import subprocess
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])


hostname = "8.8.8.8"
cmdping = "ping -c 1 " + hostname + " -I " + get_ip_address('eth0')

p = subprocess.Popen(cmdping, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

#The following while loop is meant to get you the output in real time, not to wait for the process to finish until then print the output.

while True:
    out = p.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks Khalil. from the above code. I am able to find ip address but how I can build that value as input for the command ping 8.8.8.8 -I get_ip_address('eth0')