# Get bandwidth value eth0, ifconfig on python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, network-programming, ifconfig

Get bandwidth value ifconfig on python script : How to manipulate value from ifconfig eth0 and get bandwidth value in python script, like this:

```
$python foo.py eth0
UP: 7 KB/sec
DOWN: 31 KB/sec
```

where output script can change, use Kb/s
?

Comment: You should parse `/proc/net/dev` instead of the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python. I hope so it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively parse the /proc/net/dev file. See this code on [link](http://wastedcoder.com/linux-command-implementation/linux-ifconfig-command-implementation-python)

It shows the same process.