# How to print the inner IP router with python?

Tags: python

SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH.
If I do 'ipconfig' at the cmd, I get some ips.
For example, I can get:

```
Wireless LAN adapter ‏‏Wi-Fi:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.23

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.233.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.231.1
```

But pnly one of them is the real inner ip and the other are not important.
What I need is the WIFI/DIRECT CONNECTION  IP.
I can use spliter or somthing and get this IP.
Buy the problem is:
Is there different between computers at the subject of the ip when they typy 'ipconfig'?
So for example, if I do 'ipconfig' I get the next subject:

```
Wireless LAN adapter ‏‏Wi-Fi:
```

For the one I need.
But maybe some other computers will show a different subject for a different connection with the network (for example they are connect directly and not with WIFI, and then thire subject will not have the extention 'WI-FI' like I have.).

If it is. How can I knoe the all kind of the subjects so I can alayes split the right inner ip from there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the IP address of eth0 in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python)

Comment: every computer can have many "network cards" (NIC) and all IPs are "inner" but they lets you connect to different local networks. Some computers may have only `Wi-Fi` other lan card, and other boths. Better try command `router` to see which IP gives you access to Internet.