# Force VPN Client to reconnect within Python Script

Tags: python, vpn

I wrote a small script for scraping some data. 
Unfortunately i get blocked after a certain amount of requests. Since i have a VPN client running (VPNExpress & Mac) i make a manual reconnect to the VPN client, get a new IP and keep scraping.

Is there any simple way to force my client to reconnect on its own out of a python script? E.g. turn WiFi off and on again:

`import os 
os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport off")
os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport on")`

Thought there is maybe a better way to do this? Like "blocking" the connection to force the vpn client to reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

Use `try except` to see when the requests fail. On fail, try switching off your wifi, and then switch on and then wait for `x` amount of time before checking your [ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python). If ip address isn't available, wait more until you get one. Once you get ip address, carry on scraping.