# What is " [1] ", in sock.getsockname()[1]?

Tags: python, sockets

I was going through socket programming in Python and I saw this:

`sock.getsockname()[1]`

Can anyone please explain what is that `[1]` is for?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> sock.getsockname()
('0.0.0.0', 0)
```

The first element of the returned tuple (it is a wird kind of array) `sock.getsockname()[0]` is the IP, the second one `sock.getsockname()[1]` the port.

`tuple[index]` gets the object at this index in the tuple

Answer (score 0):

`sock.getsocketname()` function returns array and `[1]` immediatelly returns you `[1]` of that array.

```
variable = sock.getsocketname()[1]
```

is equivalent to

```
arr = sock.getsocketname()
variable = arr[1]
```

In your case,  this is socket port number.

Answer (score 0):

`[1]` is how you access to the second element of a list (first element will be `[0]`).

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
print my_list[1] # => "b"
```

Because `sock.getsocketname()` returns tuple, you access to the second element like it.

A mock showing the exact same behaviour:

```
def foo():
    return ("a", "b", "c")
print foo()[1] # => "b"
```