# Getting 127.0.1.1 instead of 192.168.1.* ip ubuntu python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

I am new to python. I want to get the ipaddress of the system. I am connected in LAN. When i use the below code to get the ip, it shows 127.0.1.1 instead of 192.168.1.32. Why it is not showing the LAN ip. Then how can i get my LAN ip. Every tutorials shows this way only. I also checked via connecting with mobile  hotspot. Eventhough, it shows the same.

```
import socket    
hostname = socket.gethostname()    
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)    
print("Your Computer Name is:" + hostname)    
print("Your Computer IP Address is:" + IPAddr)
```

Output:

```
Your Computer Name is:smackcoders
Your Computer IP Address is:127.0.1.1
```

Required Output:

```
Your Computer Name is:smackcoders
Your Computer IP Address is:192.168.1.32
```

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 OS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: Can you paste the output of the following file here?  "cat /etc/hosts"

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 smackcoders

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: This line "127.0.1.1 smackcoders" is causing the DNS to resolve to 127.0.1.1. You can try removing/commenting this line and rerun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the above '/etc/hosts' file content, you have an IP address mapping with '127.0.1.1' to your hostname. This is causing the name resolution to get 127.0.1.1. You can try removing/commenting this line and rerun.

Answer (score 24):

I got this same problem with my raspi.

```
host_name = socket.gethostname()`
host_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
```

and now if i print host_addr, it will print 127.0.1.1.
So i foundthis: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=188615#p1187999

```
host_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host_name + ".local")
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I required

Answer (score 5):

[How can I get the IP address of eth0 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python)

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print s.getsockname()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

This also worked for me:

```
gethostbyname(gethostname()+'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

i get the same problem what your are facing. but I get the solution with help of my own idea, And don't worry it is simple to use.
if you familiar to linux you should heard the `ifconfig` command which return the informations about the network interfaces, and also you should understand about `grep` command which filter the lines which consist specified words
now just open the terminal and type

```
ifconfig | grep 255.255.255.0
```

and hit `enter` now you will get wlan inet address line alone like below

```
inet 192.168.43.248  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
```

in your terminal
in your python script just insert

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
cmd = "ifconfig | grep 255.255.255.0"
inet = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True)
inet = wlan.decode("utf-8")
inet = wlan.split(" ")
inet_addr = inet[inet.index("inet")+1]
print(inet_addr)
```

this script return your local ip address, this script works for me and I hope this will work for your linux machine
all the best

Answer (score -1):

This solution works for me on Windows. If you're using Linux you could try this line of code instead:

```
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: >>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
'127.0.1.1'