# Socket IO returns 127.0.0.1 as host address and not 192.168.0.* on my device

Tags: python, networking

When I run the following code to determine my device's local IP address, I get 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.0.101.

```
import socket
import threading

PORT = 8080
HOST_NAME = socket.gethostname()
print(HOST_NAME)
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(HOST_NAME)

print(SERVER)
```

The output i get on the console is

```
MyDeviceName.local
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: That is exactly what it should return, it is by design, and not a bug. 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address of IPv4. 192.168.1.101 is your ethernet address, which is then translated into a public address by your router. Your are not using the correct way to get your ethernet address.

Comment: Could you add your operating system? It might be a duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296584/getting-127-0-1-1-instead-of-192-168-1-ip-ubuntu-python

Comment: I'm using macOS Monterey

Comment: @Thyebri oh okay. I guess i will have to re-refer the docs and try again. Thanks anyways

Comment: This code is just a waste of time and space. If you know that the server is running in the same host you can hardwire "127.0.0.1" without writing any of this code at all.

Comment: @user207421 agreed, but for my use case, my server is going to be a Jetson Tx1 developer board serially connected via UART or Ethernet to the raspberry pi where data transfer happens. Now hardcoding the IP address would work but not that efficient is what i kinda felt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is localhost address, it is right. If you want your device's address do this:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
```

Comment: If I understand how this works this needs a WAN connection to reach 8.8.8.8 to function. A better solution would be able to resolve the local hosts IP address within the domain which assigned the local IP address

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> **NOTE** - Tested on CentOS 7.9 using Python 3.6.8, and Ubuntu 20.04 using Python 3.8.10

> **NOTE** - You may have to install psutil when using Ubuntu 20.04

```
import socket

import psutil

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 80))
my_eip = s.getsockname()[0]
nics = psutil.net_if_addrs()
my_enic = [i for i in nics for j in nics[i]
           if j.address == my_eip and j.family == socket.AF_INET][0]
print('My Ethernet NIC name is {0} and my IPv4 address is {1}.'.format(
    my_enic, my_eip))
```

**Output:**

```
My Ethernet NIC name is enp0s3 and my IPv4 address is 192.168.0.101.
```

Comment: If I understand how this works this needs a WAN connection to reach 8.8.8.8 to function.  A better solution would be able to resolve the local hosts IP address within the domain which assigned the local IP address.