# Socket IO returns 127.0.0.1 as host address, randomly, instead of the public IP Of the device

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket.io, dns

Trying to get host-IP Through Python, using socket module -
Occasionally, i get address 127.0.0.1 and not the real IP Address - i.e 10.210.24.24

I've adjusted my code per the answer in:

[Socket IO returns 127.0.0.1 as host address and not 192.168.0.* on my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331707/socket-io-returns-127-0-0-1-as-host-address-and-not-192-168-0-on-my-device)

But still get random encounters of 127.0.0.1.

The issue occurs in automation - Which SSH's into the remote host (10.210.24.24 for example),
And runs the below code snippet.

Trying to reproduce manually - i always get the correct IP Address.

My code is as follows:

```
    self.host_name = socket.gethostname()
    try:
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.host_name)
        if host_ip == "127.0.0.1":
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
            host_ip = s.getsockname()[0]
        self.host_ip = host_ip
    except Exception as e:     # In case DNS Resolving fails
        logger.warning("Failed setting '%s' IP | %s", self.host_name, str(e))
        self.host_ip = ""
```

I'm trying to understand what am I missing here:

1. Why would "randomly", i would get 127.0.0.1 instead of the actual host IP.
   Given the fact the host definitely has IP Assigned (Since i'm using SSH root@ in order to run the script)
2. How to overcome this issue and make sure i always get the correct IP Address?
3. In case more debug info is needed -
   What logs should i look into once this issue does occur?
   I can add "fail handling" to at least dump those logs when the issue occurs in my automation.

System is Debian 11, Python 3.9.

Thanks

Comment: Did you perform sanity checks on the variables self.host_name etc?

Comment: @JasonChia yes, in all our automations - we dump the hostName and hostIp variable.
The hostname is always correct one (and not "localhost" for example)

Comment: Well until you can reproduce your problem its going to be a real pain to diagnose. I can't reproduce it on my environment even with automated scripts....