# Convert PyQt5 WebEngine request into IP packet and vice-versa

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, interceptor, packet

With PyQt5, I have successfully set up a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor subclass, and I can modify the headers and data of the web request. I am building this for a VPN-like app, where the request gets converted into a packet (sent with scapy's `IP()` object or a similar module), encrypted and sent to another address, who will decrypt and convert the packet data back into a QWebEngine request. My question is how can one convert a web request intercepted with PyQt5 into an IP packet format, and vice-versa?

Here is the interceptor code:

```
#Custom url interceptor for modifying headers
#and the url before sending it on
class UrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor,self).__init__(parent)

  def interceptRequest(self,info):
    #Modify the actual request here - todo: block the
    #request here, packet simulate etc...
    info.setHttpHeader(b"Accept-Language",InterClassVariables.languageCode.encode())
```

Comment: What is the object type of this "IP packet" format? Is it raw bytes like a packet capture? Is it a packet built with Scapy's `IP()`? Can you post EXACTLY what the end result should look like?

Comment: It's a packet built with Scapy's `IP()` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` interacts with HTTP (layer 7) when you want IP info (layer 3). [QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html) does not have any IP properties (again it's at layer 7).

While it's possible to use Qt's [QHostInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostinfo.html), it's simpler to use vanilla Python. Here, we are using [netifaces](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/). While it's not in the standard library, [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-from-nic-in-python) are more complex, platform-dependent, or require an internet connection.

```py
import socket

from PyQt5.Qt import QUrl
from PyQt5.Qt import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
from PyQt5.Qt import QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo
import netifaces
from scapy.all import IP

#Custom url interceptor for modifying headers
#and the url before sending it on
class UrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor,self).__init__(parent)
    self.info = None

  def interceptRequest(self, info: QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo):
    #Modify the actual request here - todo: block the
    #request here, packet simulate etc...
    self.info = info
    self.info.setHttpHeader(b"Accept-Language",
      InterClassVariables.languageCode.encode())
    self.sendPacket()

  def getDestIp(self):
    qUrl = self.info.requestURL()
    url = qUrl.toString()
    dest_ip = socket.gethostbyname(url)
    return dest_ip

  def sendPacket()
    src_ip = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]
    dest_ip = get_dest_ip(self.info)
    ip_layer = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dest_ip)
    other_layers = OTHER_PROTOCOLS() # FIXME
    pkt = ip_layer/other_layers
    send(pkt) # Choose whichever send function is most appropriate here
```

If we print the packet (without other layers), we should get something similar to this:

```sh
$ python project.py -show-packet # Pseudo cli
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = None
  id        = 1
  flags     =
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = ip
  chksum    = None
  src       = 172.31.98.1
  dst       = 151.101.65.69
  \options   \
```

Comment: Thanks very much, so far working. One thing - how would I convert the received packet data back into a `QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo` object?

Comment: You would need to implement a receive_packet function and a function to construct a requestInfo object. You may need to use the machinery of the Interceptor superclass to do the latter.