# How do I get my local ip address from a python script on linux?

Tags: python, linux, ip

I am trying to run a python server on a Raspberry Pi, and I need the local IP address of it to connect. I realize I can just type ifconfig and get my IP address, but I would really like to be able to get it from the python script. I have tried `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())`, but that seems to only work on Windows. When I run it on my raspberry pi, it seems to always return `127.0.1.1`. Does anyone know a command that will get the local IP address on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an external package, for example netifaces, or you can look for the ipaddress of a given interface, specified by its name. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-from-nic-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` returns `127.0.1.1` is because you have a line similar to this in `/etc/hosts` on your raspberry pi

```
127.0.1.1 <host_name>
```

Try changing `127.0.1.1` to the static IP address of your pi and it should return correctly.