# hostname -I in python/php

Tags: python, php

I'm having PHP and Python scripts running on different machines, and I want to get the IP of the machine from these scripts.

It seems like it's directing me to the loopback device and not to the network card whenever I try this from within the machine (which is where these scripts are located).
When I called PHP script that only runs `phpinfo();` from the browser I had the wanted result but when I used curl it gave me the loopback address.

I tried multiple ways that should work

in Python:
`socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`

in PHP:
`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `getHostByName(php_uname('n'));`

The bash command `hostname -I`, is working for me since it's ignoring the loopback address. I wanted to know if there's something like this built-in PHP/Python.
Otherwise, I think my solution would be to just call this bash command from these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For python : `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`
returns values contained in /etc/hosts. I guess you have `127.0.0.1       localhost`

(check [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib))

If you want to get the ip directly on your Nic take a look at this thread, you can use external lib :
[How can I get the IP address from NIC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-from-nic-in-python)